# Selecting a solution range that is independent of a variable value

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, inequalities

This symbolic computational question derives from [this mathematical one on math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4450444/what-does-monotonously-increasing-mean/4450474#4450474):

- Find all values of $a \in \mathbb{R}$ for which $f(x;a) = x^3 - 3 a x^2 + 3 a x - 2$ is non-decreasing.

My approach is to take the derivative of $f(x;a)$:

```
D[x^3 - 3 a x^2 + 3 a x - 2, x]
```

$a - 6 a x + 3 x^2$

Then the question arises:  How to find the range of $a$ for which this is always greater than or equal to $0$, i.e., $\frac{d f(x;a)}{dx} = a - 6 a x + 3 x^2 \geq 0$.

My first thought was follows:

```
CylindricalDecomposition[a-6 a x+3 x^2>=0,{a,x}]
```

$$\left(a<0\land \left(x\leq a-\frac{\sqrt{3 a^2-a}}{\sqrt{3}}\lor x\geq \frac{\sqrt{3
   a^2-a}}{\sqrt{3}}+a\right)\right)\lor 0\leq a\leq \frac{1}{3}\lor
   \left(a>\frac{1}{3}\land \left(x\leq a-\frac{\sqrt{3 a^2-a}}{\sqrt{3}}\lor x\geq
   \frac{\sqrt{3 a^2-a}}{\sqrt{3}}+a\right)\right)$$

I thought that I need merely pick out the piece that is independent of $x$:

```
Select[%, FreeQ[#, x] &]
```

which gives:

$0 \leq a \leq 1/3$.

But this is incorrect;  the actual answer is $0 \leq a \leq 1$.

The problem is that even if the derivative *does* depend upon $x$, there are values of $a$ for which the derivative is non-negative.

What (I think!) I'm seeking is some expression that reads (in English):  "Find the range of $a$ that for all values of $x$ implies the derivative is non-negative."  There must be some logical qualification e.g., `ForAll`, that I need.

Suggestions?

Comment: `Resolve [ForAll[x, D[x^3 - 3 a x^2 + 3 a x - 2, x] >= 0]]`

Comment: @Syed:  Oh gee... thanks so much.  Perfect.  If you put this in a solution I'll accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Resolve [ForAll[x, D[x^3 - 3 a x^2 + 3 a x - 2, x] >= 0]]
```

> 0 <= a <= 1